# SwiftUI 2.0: Custom keyboard elements

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I would like to show a button on top of my iOS keyboard with SwiftUI 2.0.
I have the following code:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(viewModel.model.searchResults) {
            Text($0.name)
        }
    }
    .searchable(text: $viewModel.model.searchString,
                placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
    .toolbar(content: {
        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard, content: {
            Button(action: {}, label: {
                Text("Test")
            })
        })
    })
}
```

But I get the following result:
[image: Normal keyboard instead of button]

How can that by, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need a NavigationView

Comment: It is getting displayed inside a navigaionview via a navigation link. I also tried adding the navigationview, did not help.

Comment: I just realized you first responder is the `searchable` modifier. I don't think you can place it on that since a `UISearchBar` doesn't have a `menu` and the underlying behavior is likely a `UISearchController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it is not possible to add custom buttons with a search text field, see this answer: [How to display .toolbar on keyboard summoned by .searchable in swiftUI 3.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68782621/how-to-display-toolbar-on-keyboard-summoned-by-searchable-in-swiftui-3-0)